# casting char[][] to char** causes segfault?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, segmentation-fault

Ok my C is a bit rusty but I figured I'd make my next(small) project in C so I could polish back up on it and less than 20 lines in I already have a seg fault.

This is my complete code:

```
#define ROWS 4
#define COLS 4

char main_map[ROWS][COLS+1]={
  "a.bb",
  "a.c.",
  "adc.",
  ".dc."};

 void print_map(char** map){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
    puts(map[i]); //segfault here
  }
 }



int main(){
  print_map(main_map); //if I comment out this line it will work.
  puts(main_map[3]);
  return 0;
}
```

I am completely confused as to how this is causing a segfault. What is happening when casting from `[][]` to `**`!? That is the only warning I get.

```
rushhour.c:23:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘print_map’ from incompatible pointer type
rushhour.c:13:7: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[5]’
```

Are `[][]` and `**` really not compatible pointer types? They seem like they are just syntax to me.

Comment: "Not compatible pointer types"? What do you mean? Your `[][]` type is an *array* type, not a pointer type. Why are you referring to `[][]` as a pointer type???

Comment: @Andrey it's a big huge obvious gap in my C knowledge. I completely understand pointers but not arrays. :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A `char[ROWS][COLS+1]` cannot be cast into a `char**`. The input argument of `print_map` should be

```
void print_map(char map[][COLS+1])
```

or

```
void print_map(char (*map)[COLS+1])
```

---

The difference being that a `char**` means to point to something that can be dereferenced like this:

```
   (char**)map
       |
       v
  +--------+--------+------+--------+-- ...
  | 0x1200 | 0x1238 | NULL | 0x1200 |
  +----|---+----|---+--|---+----|---+-- ...
       v        |      =        |
    +-------+   |               |
    | "foo" | <-----------------'
    +-------+   |
                v
             +---------------+
             | "hello world" |
             +---------------+
```

While a `char(*)[n]` is a points to a continuous memory region like this

```
   (char(*)[5])map
       |
       v
  +-----------+---------+---------+-------------+-- ...
  | "foo\0\0" | "hello" | " worl" | "d\0\0\0\0" |
  +-----------+---------+---------+-------------+-- ...
```

If you treat a `(char(*)[5])` as a `(char**)` you get garbage:

```
   (char**)map
       |
       v
  +-----------+---------+---------+-------------+-- ...
  | "foo\0\0" | "hello" | " worl" | "d\0\0\0\0" |
  +-----------+---------+---------+-------------+-- ...
      force cast (char[5]) into (char*):
  +----------+------------+------------+------------+-- ...
  | 0x6f6f66 | 0x6c686500 | 0x77206f6c | 0x646c726f |
  +----|-----+---------|--+------|-----+------|-----+-- ...
       v               |         |            |
    +---------------+  |         |            v
    | "hsd®yœâñ~22" |  |         |       launch a missile
    +---------------+  |         |
                       v         v
               none of your process memory
                        SEGFAULT
```

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with a explanation as to why :) Now I'm confused for which answer is better though

Answer (score 3):

When you do this declaration:

```
char main_map[ROWS][COLS+1]={
  "a.bb",
  "a.c.",
  "adc.",
  ".dc."};
```

You create an array-of-arrays-of-char.  An array-of-char is just a block of chars, and an array-of-arrays is just a block of arrays - so overall, `main_map` is just a whole heap of chars.  It looks like this:

```
| 'a' | '.' | 'b' | 'b' | 0 | 'a' | '.' | 'c' | '.' | 0 | ... | 'd' | 'c' | '.' | 0 |
```

When you pass `main_map` to `print_map()`, it is evaluating `main_map` as a pointer to the first element of the array - so this pointer is pointing at the start of that block of memory.  You force the compiler to convert this to type `char **`.

When you evaluate `map[0]` within the function (eg. for the first iteration of the loop), it fetches the `char *` value pointed to by `map`.  Unfortunately, as you can see from the ASCII-art, `map` *doesn't* point to a `char *` - it points to a bunch of plain `char` s.  There's no `char *` values there at all.  At this point, you load some of those `char` values (4, or 8, or some other number depending on how big `char *` is on your platform) and try to interpret those as a `char *` value.

When `puts()` then tries to follow that bogus `char *` value, you get your segmentation fault.

Comment: This was what I was wanting. Was an explanation not just a quick fix. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at my code I realized that the amount of columns is constant, but it doesn't actually matter cause it's just a string. So I changed it so main_map is an array of strings(er, char pointers). This makes it so I can just use `**` for passing it around also:

```
char *main_map[ROWS]={
  "a.bb",
  "a.c.",
  "adc.",
  ".dc."};
```