# int ** vs int [ROWS][COLS]

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [casting char[][] to char** causes segfault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895433/casting-char-to-char-causes-segfault)

I have a 2D array declared like this:

```
int arr[2][2]={ {1,2},{3,4}};
```

Now if I do:

```
int ** ptr=(int**) arr;
```

and:

```
cout<<**ptr;
```

I am getting a segmentation fault (using g++-4.0).

Why so? Shouldn't it be printing the value 1 (equal to `arr[0][0]`)?

Comment: I think there is a great rule in C++: "If you have to cast, you can't afford it" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/23/9911891.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to assign a double pointer variable to an array... this has been covered exhaustively, see [here](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/26arraysaspointers.html) for information on this. Furthermore, since you declared

```
int arr[2][2] = ...;
```

and then try to assign `arr` to a double pointer

```
int ** ptr = ... ;
```

which is guaranteed to not work, hence a segmentation fault. Furthermore, that statement `int ** ptr=(int**) arr;` is actually ***cast*** ing one type (i.e. [][]) to another type (i.e. **) despite they are of type 'int'. They are both different and the compiler will interpret that very differently...

You could do it this way:

```
int *ptr = &arr;
```

Now `*(ptr + 1)`  will refer to the 0'th row, `*(ptr + 2)` will refer to the 1'st row and so on. The only onus on you is to not overstep the markers of where `arr` is used otherwise an overflow can happen or even a segmentation fault...

Answer (score 5):

You can't cast a linear array to a pointer-to-pointer type, since `int**` doesn't hold the same data `int[][]` does.
The first holds pointers-to-pointers-to-ints. The second holds a sequence of ints, in linear memory.

Comment: Well, you "can", as the OP demonstrates.  You just have to do a reinterpret_cast, which the OP unknowingly did because they're using c-style casts.  As with all such casts of course the result of accessing the new pointer is UB.  The moral the OP should be getting is: use C++ casts in C++.

Answer (score 2):

What you do now means creating of arrays of pointers where every pointer was ***explicitly casted***. Therefore, you would have an array of pointers like (`0x00001, 0x00002, 0x00003 and 0x00004`).

*When dereferenced, this pointers cause your segfault.*

Answer (score 1):

No, `int **` is a pointer to a pointer to an int, but a 2-D array is an array of arrays, and `&(arr[0][0])` is a pointer to an int.

I believe you should be doing this:

```
int *ptr = arr;
cout<<*ptr;
```

or this:

```
int *ptr = &arr[0][0];
cout<<*ptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int *ptr = arr;
```

More Explanation:

You should assign an adress to the pointer, so it can be derefenced(i mean * operator). What you do is, pointing ptr to memory cell that has the adress a[0][0]. Therefore, you get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

`int arr[2][2]` is not an array of arrays - it is a single 2d array.  In memory, it is indistinguishable from `int arr[4]`

What you really want is

```
int (*ptr)[2] = arr;
```

Comment: Formally, it *is* an array of arrays.  But yes, since arrays are laid out contiguously with no padding allowed, an `int [2][2]` is indeed laid out exactly like an `int [4]` in memory.