# How to pass MyClass[][] for MyClass**?

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, casting

Why can't I pass

```
    Point src[1][4] = {
        {
            Point(border,border), Point(border,h-border), Point(w-border,h-border), Point(w-border,h-border)
        }
    };
```

as

```
polylines(frame, src, ns, 1, true, CV_RGB(255,255,255), 2);
```

where

polylines has prototype

```
void polylines(Mat& img, const Point** pts, const int* npts, int ncontours, bool isClosed, const Scalar& color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, int shift=0 )
```

**UPDATE**

Okay, okay, I remembered this stuff :)

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 4):

`Point[1][4]` can't be converted to `Point**` this way.
Have a look at this question: [Converting multidimensional arrays to pointers in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1584100/1168156)

The actual solution here is to ***use STL container instead of C-style array***, e.g. `std::vector`:

```
typedef std::vector<Point> Shape;
std::vector<Shape> myShapes;
...
```

and pass it by `const` reference instead of `const` pointer:

```
void polylines(Mat& img, const std::vector<Shape>& shapes, ...)
```

Also note that `src`, `ns`, `pts`, etc. aren't very lucky names for your variables. Try to choose more meaningful names... if not for your own sake, then do it for the sake of future readers of that code :)

Answer (score 2):

Because they're not the same thing. `polylines` asks for a pointer to *pointers* to `Point`, but you're giving it a pointer to array[4] of `Point`.

Rephrased: When you use `src` as an expression like this, it decays from an array into a pointer. In this case it will decay from `Point[1][4]` into `Point(*)[4]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of size 4 of type `Point`. This is the memory location of the 4 `Point` objects. `polylines` expects the memory location of a *pointer* to a `Point` object.

Answer (score 1):

Array-of-arrays and pointer-to-pointers do not imply the same memory layout. An array-of-array contains all of its elements contiguously, whereas a pointer-to-pointers requires an array of contiguous pointers which point to (possibly non-contiguous) arrays of contiguous elements.

To do that conversion, you would need to allocate an array of pointers and have them point to the correct entries in your array-of-arrays. In your case, since you have a single set of values, it's even simpler:

```
Point * pointer = &src[0][0];
int npts = 4;
polylines(img, &pointer, &npts, 1, ...);
```

Assuming `ncontours` is the number of pointers to which the pointer-to-pointer points and `npts` is the number of points to which the individual pointers point.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this question: [casting char[][] to char** causes segfault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895433/casting-char-to-char-causes-segfault?rq=1)

Short answer: **You should never do that**