# C++: Semantics of [x] for dereferencing: C-style vs pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays

I know that a c style array is stored as a contiguous block of memory. That is why the following code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int arr[3][3];
    *(*arr + 5) = 5;
    std::cout << arr[1][2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

prints 5. I assume that for c style arrays `*(*arr + 5) = 5;` is roughly equals to the code which the compiler produces for `arr[1][2] = 5;` isn't it? (Q1)

If so, then the semantics of arr[1][2] (i.e. shifting on one block of memory) is totally different from doing the same on a multidimensional pointer array where every level of nesting results in a pointer being dereferenced. Is that right? (Q2)

Is there any situation where I need to pay attention to that myself? I.e. where the compiler does not know himself what kind of array he is dealing with? (Q3)

(Qx marks my questions)

Thank you in advance and Regards

Comment: Don't missunderstood me, your questions are interesting, but please avoid multiquestion posts and do one question per post.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's technically undefined behaviour to do that, even if no compiler today will do anything bad.

Comment: For question 2, I think this could be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895433/casting-char-to-char-causes-segfault

Comment: In general, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On one hand, you're talking about a two dimensional array, which you can imagine looks something like this in memory:

```
 0,0 0,1 0,2 1,0 1,1 1,2 2,0 2,1 2,2
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│int│int│int│int│int│int│int│int│int│
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

On the other hand, when you have an array of pointers to arrays, it looks like this:

```
┌────┬────┬────┐
│int*│int*│int*┿━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
└─╂──┴─╂──┴────┘              ┃
  ┃    ┗━━━━━━━━┓             ┃
  ▼             ▼             ▼
┌───┬───┬───┐ ┌───┬───┬───┐ ┌───┬───┬───┐
│int│int│int│ │int│int│int│ │int│int│int│
└───┴───┴───┘ └───┴───┴───┘ └───┴───┴───┘ 
 0,0 0,1 0,2   1,0 1,1 1,2   2,0 2,1 2,2
```

Both of these can be indexed using the same `[i][j]` syntax. The `[]` operator is defined as `x[i]` being equivalent to `*((x) + (i))`. If we index `x[1][1]`, we have `*((*((x) + (1)) + (1))`.

In the first case above, first the array name `x` undergoes array-to-pointer conversion to get a pointer to its first element (which is itself an array, so we have a `int (*)[3]`), then we add `1` to it to move along to the next subarray and dereference it. This subarray then also undergoes array-to-pointer conversion to get a pointer to its first element, which we add `1` to again and dereference. So what we end up with the end is the 2nd element in the 2nd subarray.

In the second case, we are dealing with an array of pointers. First the array name `x` undergoes array-to-pointer conversion to get a pointer to its first element (which is a `int*`). Then we add `1` to it to move to the next pointer in the array and it is dereferenced to get the `int*` itself. Then we add `1` to this `int*` to move along to the next `int` after the one it is currently pointing at and we dereference that. That again gives us the 2nd element in the 2nd array of `int`s.

So, given all that:

1. Yes, since the elements of the 2D array are contiguous, you can do pointer arithmetic where you treat it as a 1D array with 9 `int`s in it.
2. Yes, the memory layout of the data in each case is different, so the operations that occur when indexing into them are different.
3. The compiler always knows which type it is dealing with. The compiler won't let you, for example, attempt to convert a 2D array to a `int**`. They are simply incompatible. However, *you* generally need to make sure you know what the memory layout of your data is.

---

Sometimes you have the following kind of layout where you have an `int**`, particularly common when you dynamically allocate an array of pointers that point to dynamically allocated arrays:

```
┌─────┐
│int**│
└─╂───┘
  ▼
┌────┬────┬────┐
│int*│int*│int*┿━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
└─╂──┴─╂──┴────┘              ┃
  ┃    ┗━━━━━━━━┓             ┃
  ▼             ▼             ▼
┌───┬───┬───┐ ┌───┬───┬───┐ ┌───┬───┬───┐
│int│int│int│ │int│int│int│ │int│int│int│
└───┴───┴───┘ └───┴───┴───┘ └───┴───┴───┘ 
 0,0 0,1 0,2   1,0 1,1 1,2   2,0 2,1 2,2
```

The process of indexing this layout is almost exactly the same as the second case above. The only difference is that the first array-to-pointer conversion is not necessary because we already have a pointer.

Comment: +1 Oh, I have nothing to do with my answer if you draw this awesome ascii diagrams.. :)

Comment: Thanks, I always find diagrams useful for understanding the C++ object model. I tend to have diagrams forming in my mind when I'm coding.

Comment: Me too. I have always this Stroupstrup's image in my mind :) http://bulldozer00.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/mem-layout.png?w=595

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive answer. Obviously for c style arrays the compiler needs to know the size of every but the first dimension. Is that also a reason for why c style arrays don't exist on heap? (They don't if I'm not totally off the road)

Comment: @sftrabbit  Hi!May i ask how to type these ascii characters? some of them are not shown on keyboard

Comment: @richard.g I always just copy them from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) when I need them.

Comment: @sftrabbit that's cruel ┘┬└. I had thought that you might have used alt codes to type them.

Comment: @richard.g Yeah, I could probably do with learning how to type them, but there's so many. In fact, it'd be nice if there was a tool for drawing these diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: This is called *pointer arithmetic*. An array of integers is technically just an `int*` in practical use, and adding 1 to a pointer makes the pointer point to the next item in the list. Address-wise it's equivalent to raising the in-memory address with `sizeof(int)`.

Q2: While syntactically equivalent, the compiler treats it differently because it knows to treat differently because of the declaration. If `arr` is an `int**` the internals are compiled as a multidimensional pointer array, if it's an `int[x][y]` it just does the maths for you inside and keeps it flat, hence why the pointer arithmetic still works.

Q3: No, if the compiler wouldn't know what it was dealing with it would be a fundamental flaw in the language. This is actually pretty well defined.

Answer (score 0):

A1: Static multidimension arrays (2D in this case) can be accessed using either 2D or 1D indexes. The elements are one after the other w/o gaps.

A2: the compiler knows the relevant offsets at compile time so a[x][y] is actually a single pointer dereference.

A3: The compiler always know the type and will produce code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer 1:

You are correct. A multiimensional array is only a contiguous block of arrays, where that arrays are contiguous blocks of elements too. So when you create an array like this:

```
    int array[n1][n2]...[nm];
```

What the compiler does is to allocate a `n1 * n2 * ... * nm` length unidimensional contiguous array. Thats why your `*(*array + 5)` works.
In fact when you index elements of a multidimensional array:
        array[index_1][index_2]...[index_m] = 0;
What the compiler really does is something like this:

```
    array[index_1 * ( n1 * n2 * ... * n(m-1) ) + index_2 * ( n1 * n2 * ... * n(m-2) ) + .. + index_m] = 0;
```

#### Answer 2:

Multidimensional arrays are not the same as pointers to pointers to pointers to pointers... Multidimensional arrays are, as I said before, continious regions of aligned memory, and dynamic arrays of pointers to dynamic arrays of pointers to... are arrays which elements are pointers. Thats is, things that are dessigned to be dereferenced. Thats why treating a `**array` as an `array[][]` may fail, and biceversa. For more info about this topic, see this thread: [casting char[][] to char** causes segfault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895433/casting-char-to-char-causes-segfault)

Answer (score -1):

if you define

```
int arr[A][B];
```

then

```
arr[x][y]
```

is actually

```
*(arr+x*B+y) //array name can be treated as memory location or const pointer
```

so, double dereference in your code is wrong. <== This line is wrong. Sorry.

Comment: Hm as I stated the code that I posted runs on my machine. Also I actually think your code does not run as expected. AFAIK in *(arr+A*x+y) the part: A*x+y will result in some number which is then multiplied by: sizeof(int) * A. But I would be glad if somebody could conform that as I'm not an expert here.

Comment: Double dereference is right, the point is that `*arr` is of type `int (*)[3]`.

Comment: @user2820379 sorry for typping mistake. Corrected.

Comment: @Matteo Italia In defenition `int arr[A][B];`, arr can only be dereference once.

Comment: @SliceSort: nope. You dereference once and you get an `int (*)[3]`, you dereference again and you get an `int`. If you could dereference only once expressions like `a[x][y]`,  which is (by *definition* of the subscript operator) `*(*(a+x)+y)`, couldn't work.

Comment: @Matteo Italia Sorry for my wrong answer and thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Look up the [array FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/) and see by yourself.